# Is there an equivalent to ConvertTimeFromUtc in MS SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there a function in SQL Server that will convert a DateTime saved as UTC time to the local time? The problem is that I have times saved as UTC times, and I used to calculate time zone offset as

> select @tzoffset = datediff(mi,SYSDATETIMEOFFSET(),SYSDATETIME())

and adding that to my UTC times, which worked fine until daylight saving came.
As that selects the **current** time zone offset, the calculation is invalid for pre-DST values.

As the dates are rendered in ASP.NET web form, I have worked around the issue by rendering the dates as `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc((DateTime)Eval("maxtime"), TimeZoneInfo.Local)`, which works automagically.

Is there something similarly elegant in T-SQL?

Answer (score 1):

It is not that simple. Read this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2009/03/31/the-death-of-datetime.aspx